# Conda environments only working with base version Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I have started to learn how to work with creating new virtual environments. However whenever I try to launch a Jupyter Notebook I find that going through the dropdown menu and selecting the kernel name results in

> Kernel starting, please wait...

followed by connection failed.

Very simply my approach is:

```
conda create --name py37 python==3.7.2 

#activate
conda activate py37
conda install pandas

conda install ipykernel

ipython kernel install --user --display-name "guacamole"
```

Now when I locate the folder where the kernels are created:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels

What I find is that for the kernel.json file, when argv is set to "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe" then my kernel loads fine in Jupyter

When argv is set to
"C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\py37\python.exe" it fails to load.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being very straight forward. While I feel a bit silly I didn't click at first I learnt a fair bit about virtual environments in the process!

All that was necessary was to simply run the following **once I had activated the environment** (in Anaconda prompt)

```
jupyter notebook
```

The problem was that I was running a jupyter notebook from a different location hence the clash. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run jupyter notebook from any environment, and be able to select the kernel from the dropdown. No need to exit and change directory.

```
conda activate py37
python -m ipykernel install --user --name py37 --display-name "guacamole"

# then, to test 
conda deactivate
jupyter notebook
```